# Firefox Add-on How to Link context menu and panel widget

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, contextmenu, panel, firefox-addon-sdk

I want open/show my panel widget by click on my context-menu item to send some data from the dom position click to my panel.

I'm open for lot of solutions !

Comment: would you like to see a bootstrap solution? which means not sdk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this works but try it out, its sdk style

```
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var self = require("sdk/self");

var panel = panels.Panel({
  contentURL: self.data.url("panel.html")
});

var cm = require("sdk/context-menu");
cm.Item({
  label: "Edit Image",
  context: cm.SelectorContext("img"),
  contentScript: 'self.on("click", function () {' +
                 '  self.postMessage(null);' +
                 '});',
  onMessage: function (msg) {
  panel.show({
    //position: button //set position to some anchor
  });
  }
});
```